# Let & Var different output

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Here are the two code snippets, I am using "var" keyword in one and "let" in another. why the outcomes are so different.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i);
  }, 100);
}
```

output: 
***0
1
2
3
4***

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i);
  }, 100);
}
```

Output: 
**5 
5
5
5
5**

Comment: tl;dr: Because `let` is block scoped and `var` is not.

Comment: They are different keywords that do different things, all the documentation for `let` explains clearly why it was introduced as an alternative to `var`. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) is an excellent resource for  learning the ins and outs of JavaScript.